# Implementing Simple Slider by loopj

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that when clicked creates a slider.

HTML:

```
<a id="slider"class = "button small">Create Slider</a>
```

JS:

```
$('#slider').click(function(eventClick, posX, posY){
     var htmlData='<div id="sldr'+$.count+'" class="draggable"' + 'data-page="' + $.page + '" ';
     htmlData += 'style="height:25px; width:360px"><input id="movingslider'+$.count+'" class="sldr" type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="10,1000"><span class="output"></span><a href="#" class="delete"></a></div>';
     var temp = $.count
     $('.demo').append(htmlData);   
     $('#movingslider'+temp).simpleSlider();
     $('#movingslider'+temp).bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
     $(this).nextAll(".output:first").html((data.value.toFixed(3)));
     });
        $('#sldr'+temp).draggable({
            containment: "#workspace",
            scroll: false,
            cancel: false,
        }
     })     
     $('a.delete').on('click',function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           btnID = $(this).closest('.draggable')[0].id;
           //alert('Now deleting "'+objID+'"');
           $('#'+btnID+'').remove();
       });
    $.count++;
});
```

I'm having some problem with the values of the newly created slider. I've indicated that the ranges should be from 10-1000 but when I started scrolling the slider, it shows the default range, 0-1. How could I change the range printed?

Answer (score 0):

Within the configuration of the slider you can specify the range and steps:

data-slider-range:

The range representing the start and end of the slider. Eg. data-slider-range="10,1000"

data-slider-step:

The interval to move when dragging the slider. Eg. data-slider-step="100"

then you can access the value of the slider as:

```
$("#movingslider").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  // The currently selected value of the slider
  alert(data.value);

  // The value as a ratio of the slider (between 0 and 1)
  alert(data.ratio);
});
```